# How to use vim abbreviation in latex?

Tags: vim, latex, abbreviation

I want to set some abbreviations for my latex document. Following [this](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/13.html) instructions, I typed in my `.vimrc` file

```
:autocmd FileType latex :iabbrev <buffer> lambda \lambda
```

But when I type `lambda` into my `tex` document nothing happens. Why?

Edit: Some info

I have a line above that works:

```
:autocmd FileType latex :let localleader="\\"
```

`set ft` returns `filetype=tex` and `abbreviate lambda` returns `no abbreviation found`

Second edit:

I changed the order of my `.vimrc` file from

```
:autocmd FileType latex :let localleader="\\"
:autocmd FileType tex :iabbrev <buffer> lambda \lambda
```

to

```
:autocmd FileType tex :iabbrev <buffer> lambda \lambda
:autocmd FileType latex :let localleader="\\"
```

And now things seem to work properly.

Comment: What does `set ft?` return? Does `:abbreviate lambda` return anything?

Comment: @Marth I edited my question with some more information. The ``filetype`` is ``tex`` and the abbreviation is not defined.

Comment: What if you change FileType to tex? `autocmd FileType tex :iabbrev <buffer> lambda \lambda`. That seems to work for me.

Comment: What's weird is that if your previous `autocmd` works this one should to (ie the syntax is correct). What's weirder is that your previous `autocmd` works if the filetype is `tex`. Also, just checking, but you did type a non-keyword character after typing "lambda"?

Comment: Do you have an autoclosing plugin?

Comment: @Duikboot Switching to ``tex`` in the relevant line doesn't change anything

Comment: @Marth, I agree that this is weird. Also, I placed a ``space`` after ``lambda`` without luck

Comment: @romainl I don't think so. I don't have it directly, but I might have it via some proxy. I use ``pathogen`` and this are the folders in ``~/.vim/bundle``: ``gundo  jedi-vim  tasklist  vim-markdown  vimtex``

Comment: Try to disable `vimtex`?

Comment: @VanLaser Yes this does solve this issue. However, I do want to use vimtex... Bonus question. When I run ``:source ~/.vimrc`` the commands are not executed. I have to restart vim for that.